# Why was the election briefly started and then moved back to nominations today?

Tags: discussion, election

The election briefly started voting today and then was returned back to nominations, why?

Answer (score 10):

This is History's graduation election, and thus we need at least one more candidate than the number of spots to move ahead with an election.

The election moving into voting is an automatic process, but extending the nomination phase before voting is a manual step - and we failed to do that before the hour, so the election incorrectly moved ahead.

We've reverted the process, discarded votes that were cast, and extended the nomination period for another week - we'll need one more candidate by next Monday.

Anyone who voted today will be able to vote again normally next week.

Comment: For the record: will the voting phase resume the moment a 5th candidate steps up or exactly on next Monday?

Comment: I might make the observation that given what's happening in the real-world in the next week (building up to next Tuesday), a lot of our userbase might be a bit distracted right now.

Comment: @T.E.D. Considering the deadline is next Monday, a day before next Tuesday, they just might be distracted a tad too long.

Comment: @Mast exactly on next Monday

Comment: What happens if we don't get another nomination by Monday? Would we get another extension?

Comment: @Semaphore No, it's one extension per election, if we don't have another nomination by Monday we'll have to cancel the election and consider it a failed one

Comment: There are currently 4 candidates and 4 open positions (at least last time I checked). Why not simply give each of the 4 candidates a position?

Comment: @Chipster per our rules for elections, they have to be competitive for graduated sites. Since this is History's graduation election, we need a competitive one (which means candidates +1 at least)

Comment: @CesarM Ah. That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.